# Dropdown filter submitted on page load

Tags: php, mysql, variables, drop-down-menu

I am using the following code to select a variable for a query. I need a value/variable to be automatically selected when the page loads.

```
$ID_SOCIEDAD = $_POST['Country'];

echo "<form name='country_list' method='POST' action='http://opben.com/colombia/familias-de-carteras' >";

echo "<select name='Country' >";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

                   echo " <option selected value='". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] ."'>". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Name'] ."</option>";

                  }
       echo "     </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Filter' />";
 echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
        <?=($_POST['country']== $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code']) ?"selected='selected'" : "" ?>
```

or

```
        echo ($_POST['country']== $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code']) ?"selected='selected'" : "";
```